# Alternative SQL Query under another query for faster execution

Tags: sql

I have this SQL query:

```
UPDATE [FXdb].[dbo].[Record] 
SET [Trust_Balance]  = (
(SELECT [Bid]
 FROM [FX].[dbo].[FX_Rate]
 WHERE [FX].[dbo].[FX_Rate].[CCY1]= (SELECT [CCY]
                                     FROM [FXdb].[dbo].[Balance]
                                     WHERE SUBSTRING([FXdb].[dbo].[Balance].[CLINO], PATINDEX('%[^0]%', [FXdb].[dbo].[Balance].[CLINO]+'.'), LEN([FXdb].[dbo].[Balance].[CLINO]))=SUBSTRING(RIGHT([FXdb].[dbo].[Record].[Client_Account_Number], LEN([FXdb].[dbo].[Record].[Client_Account_Number]) - 1), PATINDEX('%[^0]%', RIGHT([FXdb].[dbo].[Record].[Client_Account_Number], LEN([FXdb].[dbo].[Record].[Client_Account_Number]) - 1)+'.'), LEN(RIGHT([FXdb].[dbo].[Record].[Client_Account_Number], LEN([FXdb].[dbo].[Record].[Client_Account_Number]) - 1)))))
* 
(SELECT [TRUST] FROM [FXdb].[dbo].[Balance]
 WHERE SUBSTRING([FXdb].[dbo].[Balance].[CLINO], PATINDEX('%[^0]%', [FXdb].[dbo].[Balance].[CLINO]+'.'), LEN([FXdb].[dbo].[Balance].[CLINO]))=SUBSTRING(RIGHT([FXdb].[dbo].[Record].[Client_Account_Number], LEN([FXdb].[dbo].[Record].[Client_Account_Number]) - 1), PATINDEX('%[^0]%', RIGHT([FXdb].[dbo].[Record].[Client_Account_Number], LEN([FXdb].[dbo].[Record].[Client_Account_Number]) - 1)+'.'), LEN(RIGHT([FXdb].[dbo].[Record].[Client_Account_Number], LEN([FXdb].[dbo].[Record].[Client_Account_Number]) - 1)))))
```

I get what I want to get which is the calculated new amount based on the money exchange rates. But my problem is it takes too long, 50 mins to be exact, for the complete result as the tables have many records.
Is there another way I can optimize this to achieve faster result?

Thank you.

Comment: see the link referenced to know on  how to ask a perfect question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: `SUBSTRING .. = SUBSTRING ..` prevents any index usage. If possible refactor the tables involved so this data element is a separate column.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?